# Why nothing happens when installing this sublimetext plugin?

Tags: sublimetext

I installed today portable version of Sublimetext3 from http://www.sublimetext.com/3. It works but when I try installing this package for powershell https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3 I only got this in console :

```
>>> import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'eb2297e1a458f27d836c04bb0cbaf282' + 'd0e7a3098092775ccb37ca9d6b2e4b7d'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
174110
```

When restarting sublimetext my powsershell script is still black and white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it doesn't look like you actually installed the [`PowerShell`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PowerShell) plugin. Once you've entered the code from the Package Control Installation page in the console and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll need to restart Sublime (which it looks like you did). Then, open the Command Palette and enter ***`pci`*** to bring up the `Package Control: Install Package` option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, wait until the menu populates, then type ***`powershell`*** to find the `PowerShell` plugin. Once it's highlighted, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again and watch the status bar at the bottom of the window as it will tell you when the package has been installed. You should now be able to open `.ps1`, `.psm1`, and `.psd1` Powershell scripts and have syntax highlighting.